# AnimationDrawable start() vs ImageView setImageDrawable(...) on Android

Tags: android, animation

I have 2 png`s with some fixeble size(a.png and b.png) 
I have a button. I want to have situation when touch on button and release some animation (for example 1 frame- a.png, 2 frame - b.png)
When I have xml:

```
...
  <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView_id"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/a"
        />
 ...
```

When I

```
 view.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.b));
```

in OnClick(...) interface I get my goal(change image in ImageView)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmbOE.png),
But when I make

```
AnimationDrawable pro2 = (AnimationDrawable)view.getBackground();
    pro2.start();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyS8w.png).

I make Animation  with animation-list and 2 items with a.png and b.png, Why I cant set animation instead setImageDrawable(...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not clear but i suppose you want to do the same task with animation Drawable for that you need to create an xml drawable of animation-list and then set it as background in the imageview . You can refer [this link](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/frame-animations-in-android/) for more understanding on this topic .

A little snippet to achieve this effect

```
ImageView mImageViewFilling = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview_animation_list_filling);
((AnimationDrawable) mImageViewFilling.getBackground()).start();
```

Comment: Thanks, this link helps me,I change android:src="@drawable/a" to android:background="@drawable/somename" and it work